# Define the specific one of 3 download file with redirect & "click here"

Tags: powershell, redirect, download, invoke-webrequest, invoke-restmethod

**How can i Download this File ?no matter how **
I am not looking for a bug in my code or the possibility to use a specific variant. = Im now Open for everything :D

MainSite`https://www.lcpdfr.com/downloads/gta5mods/character/37581-german-federal-eup-4k-alle-deutschen-polizeiuniformen-bpol-und-zoll/`

> Required Version is:  GFEUP V3.zip

Why?!
I create a AutoModDownloader.bat. This downloads the mods & sorts them.

```
because $Game + $Mods = $Setting 
$Setting = very complicated 

$Game      = GTAV
$Mod       = LspdFR
$Setting() = German
```

For me & for publication.

Generally downloading with powershell & (+) is not difficult. But on lcpdfr.com I do not understand.
There are many possibilities but I can't put the parameters together.

The method I have been trying to understand for the longest time:-

```
 $OutFile ="C:\users\public\downloads\SettingByHedda\GFEUPV3.zip"
 $Uri     =Invoke-Webrequest"https://fr.int-cdn.lcpdfrusercontent.com/monthly_2022_12/287532664_GFEUPV3_zip.60535e208eff8e1dc13b010494a60b84?st=K_sF3kkz5nsgMLw0Gd9KpQ&e=1694574832&p=10240&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27GFEUP%2520V3.zip&response-content-type=application%2Fzip%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8"

$Uri.links| where {$_.outerHTML -eq "click here"} | select -expand href | -outfile $OuFfile
```

```
Invoke-Webrequest : 401 Authorization Required
```

There are supposedly many variants.
I have tried too much to explain xD
I'm a bit overwhelmed at the moment.

This method seemed reasonable to me.

```
$uri="https://fr.int-cdn.lcpdfrusercontent.com/monthly_2022_12/287532664_GFEUPV3_zip.60535e208eff8e1dc13b010494a60b84?st=K_sF3kkz5nsgMLw0Gd9KpQ&e=1694574832&p=10240&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27GFEUP%2520V3.zip&response-content-type=application%2Fzip%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8"   
$OutFile="C:\users\public\downloads"
$file_ID="287532664"
$version_ID="3.0"
$Headers="GFEUPV3_zip"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($URI + $file_ID + "/content?version=" + $version_ID) -Headers $Headers -outFile $Outfile -Method Get
```

So more precise information was needed

[here are all 3 available downloads with any ?RPC correl ID?.....]https://www.lcpdfr.com/downloads/gta5mods/character/37581-german-federal-eup-4k-alle-deutschen-polizeiuniformen-bpol-und-zoll/?do=debugNg

in the hope to find information I have written and sorted the links also under each other

```
#_Version_=|__________________MainSite_________|____Date_______|____??____|_________Name0_____|______________Kennung0__________|__________Kennung1_______|___Kennung2_|_______________________Content_->______________________Name1_|_______________|_______DownloadName______|________________FileTyp_->__________zip__|___Kennung3___|
#V208.="    //fr.int-cdn.lcpdfrusercontent.com/monthly_2021_12 /1221735565_      GFEUPV2.8_zip.3b429922afa59a4bf83d9b621a0fe88d?st=igojnWKN0q325KvJ9_tDhA&e=1694586024&p=10240&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27 1221735565_GFEUPV2.8.zip&response-content-type=application%2Fzip%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8"
#V2081="    //fr.int-cdn.lcpdfrusercontent.com/monthly_2022_01/  698934259_    GFEUPV2.8.1_zip.e9be5fcab3f25a7d62e905a0d4170608?st=2effLd_psACeDBPaitPKFA&e=1694585895&p=10240&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27698934259_GFEUPV2.8.1.zip&response-content-type=application%2Fzip%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8"
#V3000="    //fr.int-cdn.lcpdfrusercontent.com/monthly_2022_12  /287532664_        GFEUPV3_zip.60535e208eff8e1dc13b010494a60b84?st=K_sF3kkz5nsgMLw0Gd9KpQ&e=1694574832&p=10240&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27         GFEUP%2520V3.zip&response-content-type=application%2Fzip%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8"
```

However, I don't understand putting the information in the code correct.

Does anyone have a solution ?
The only requirement is that this solution works as .bat & on any² PC.
²=on which GTA5 works xD ... without that someone has to download a "foreign" program

greets
:)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is too much of a story. Just choose the best piece of code you got so far, and show us what is not working for you. Keep it as simple as possible and place all details as text into your question.